# How to setup session and user_id as soon as the method is called? (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have these two methods responsible for adding users from another system in that system.

```
private function api_login($email, $password){

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.#.com.br/v1/driver/login",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3000,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'device_name' => 'web']),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ],
    ]);

    $response_body = curl_exec($curl);
    $response_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $response_error = curl_errno($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    $token = false;
    if (!$err) {
        if($response_code == 200){
            $json_decode = json_decode($response_body);
            $token = $json_decode->token;
        }
    }
    
    return $token;
}

private function api_user_info(){

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.#.com.br/v1/driver/user",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3000,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->session->userdata('token_#'),
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ],
    ]);

    $response_body = curl_exec($curl);
    $response_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $response_error = curl_errno($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    $json_decode = '';
    if (!$err) {
        if($response_code == 200){
            $json_decode = json_decode($response_body);
        }
    }
    
    return $json_decode;

}
```

I want to set the parameters of the following method:

```
public function stripe_payment($user_id = "", $payment_request_from = "", $session_id = "") {
        if ($this->session->userdata('user_login') != 1 && $payment_request_from == 'from_web'){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', get_phrase('please_login_first'));
            redirect('home/login', 'refresh');
        }

    //THIS IS HOW I CHECKED THE STRIPE PAYMENT STATUS
    $response = $this->payment_model->stripe_payment($user_id, $session_id);

    if ($response['payment_status'] === 'succeeded') {
        // STUDENT ENROLMENT OPERATIONS AFTER A SUCCESSFUL PAYMENT

        $check_duplicate = $this->db->get_where('bundle_payment', array('user_id' => $user_id, 'session_id' => $session_id, 'transaction_id' => $response['transaction_id']))->num_rows();
        if($check_duplicate <= 0):
            $this->course_bundle_model->bundle_purchase('stripe', $response['paid_amount'], $response['transaction_id'], $session_id);
            $this->email_model->bundle_purchase_notification($user_id);

            $this->session->set_userdata('checkout_bundle_price', null);
            $this->session->set_userdata('checkout_bundle_id', null);
        else:
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', site_phrase('session_time_out'));
            redirect('home/course_bundles', 'refresh');
        endif;

        if($payment_request_from == 'from_web'):
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', site_phrase('payment_successfully_done'));
            redirect('home/my_bundles', 'refresh');
        else:
            //for mobile
        endif;
    }else{
        if($payment_request_from == 'from_web'):
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', $response['status_msg']);
            redirect('home', 'refresh');
        else:
            //for mobile
        endif;

    }

}
```

And i need to set up this params with the result of the api above.